# Automatically merging a fork to the master

Tags: git

I am trying to setup a flow in Git but I have no clue on how to start on it.
We have a master which will be forked by some teams.
When the teams are done, they will issue a pull request to the master.
Once the PR has been approved, the fork should automatically be merged with the master. Once there is a conflict which cannot be resolved automatically, the process should stop and notify us so we can check the merge and, if needed, merge manually.

I found some solutions to update the fork from the master, but not the other way around. Any ideas on this one?

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Comment: To be honest what you're trying to do sounds overcomplicated. Most GIT UIs (TFS/GitHub etc) provide a checkbox which says "complete PR" You may find yourself putting a lot of effort into this to solve a problem which has already been solved.

Comment: Why don't prescribe the approvers to merge PRs themselves?

Answer (score 2):

A pull request is supposed to be that one manual step to double check things.

- Are the repositories up to date?
- Can the pull request be merged?

Good practice is to add some checks of your own:

- Using a builder to build and test your code
- Have reviewers or mergers take a look at what is going to change and whether that is desired or not.

Having said that, you can achieve the goal from your question by creating a custom script that uses the usual git commands. For more information about these, have a look at [forking-vs-merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611256/forking-vs-branching-in-github) and [pull-updates-from-origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903817/pull-new-updates-from-original-github-repository-into-forked-github-repository).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Are there any best practices on how this script should be written? Is it just a batch-file in your pipeline or can you attach it to the PR-flow?

Comment: The best practice is exactly to not automate pull requests. It's a critical point of approval. Any point there after can be automated and if you so wish you can apply continuous deployment.

Comment: I may have not described it clear enough. I am not trying to automate the PR but everything after that, when the PR has been approved.

Comment: That is not what i understand from your question even when i read it now. Please create a new question if you want to learn about continuous integration best practices.